# Responsive height proportional to width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Is it possible to implement the following logic usic HTML and CSS?

```
width: 100%;
height: 30% of width;
```

What I want to implement:
If I decrease the width, the height will also decrease proportionally.

Comment: what's the final goal you want to accompish by doing so? I think you'll need javascript to do such a thing

Answer (score 62, accepted):

### Padding %

This can be achieved by giving the element `height:0` and `padding-bottom:30%`.

In all browsers, when padding is specified in %, it's calculated relative to the parent element's width. This can be a very useful feature for Responsive Design.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/agtyt/3/)

In the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/agtyt/3/), the blue box at the top of the page is a single `div`. The height is responsive, and it can contain a variable amount of inline content without increasing the height. It tested fine in IE7/8/9/10, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera.

```
.content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 30%;
}
...
<div class="content"></div>
```

### Padding % and absolute position

If there are any problems with using a 0-height element, the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/agtyt/3/) also has a green box that's implemented using a wrapper element and absolute position. Not sure if there are any advantages to this approach.

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 30%;
}
.wrapper .content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
...
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow! I was searching for a solution to my problem and found this perfect solution... 7 years later! To answer your question, I prefer the 2nd solution, specially when dealing with images of different sizes: it's easier to align images when the position is absolute.

Answer (score 13):

This is now possible on modern browsers with `vw` and `vh` units:

```
width: 100vw;
height: 30vw; /* 30% of width */
```

Browser support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Yeah!

Comment: +1 for a modern solution. Just keep in mind that vm support is for IE9 and above! (Not including support for vmin and vmax)

Comment: Unfortunately this is based on the size of the viewport, not the size of the parent element.

Answer (score 3):

Also with JQuery, you could do:

```
$(window).ready(function () {
    var ratio = 3 / 10, $div = $('#my_proportional_div');
    $div.height($div.width() * ratio);
    $(window).bind('resize', function() { $div.height($div.width() * ratio); });
});
```

because the **Padding %** solution suggested doesn't work with `max/min-width` and `max-min height`.